# Google Tag Manager - Link Click Listener Check Validation option

Tags: google-analytics, links, tag-manager

What does the "Check Validation" option for a Link Click Listener mean?  The description says "Only fire tags when the action of opening a link is considered valid", but what does that actually mean?

I haven't been able to find any documentation on the option, just people saying "...you normally want to have this checked", and a few people saying it makes it so unsuccessful forms submission are not counted.

In my case, I'm dealing with a link to a PDF.  With "Check Validation" checked, the Link Click event does not fire.  If I un-check "Check Validation" the Link Click event fires, hence I am trying to figure out why that might be..?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's for form submission validation. I was attempting to set up GA tracking through GTM yesterday and needed to track successful form submissions when someone enters their credit card info. 
If the credit card details were entered correctly and the site visitor progresses tot he next page - fire event.
If however the details were not entered correctly and the visitor is prompted to correct the form on submission, do not fire event.

Comment: Any idea what it means in terms of clicking a link?

Comment: Just saw this now. The Check Validation doesn't do form validation (ie. check your form is data entered correctly or not). You still need to do that yourself. Here's a posting from Google Product forums with a bit more detail: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/cvvPLUhhLKA